# How to add the -include argument to a target using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I think the title says it all. I know how to do this using

```
add_definitions(-include <myfile.h>)
```

However, since I'm doing some shenanigans with this (using a macro to redefine a function in a library whose dependencies I'm mocking and whose source I'd prefer to leave untouched), I want this "meta" #include to only apply to one CMake target.

Is it possible to achieve this using some form of the

```
target_compile_definitions()
```

or some similar syntax with limited scope?

Comment: "Is it possible to achieve this using some form of the `target_compile_definitions()` ..?" - Yes, just try. But as `-include` is not a compile definition (definition of the macro), it is better to use general `target_compile_options()` instead.

Comment: Perfect! @Tsyvarev if you post this as an answer I'll accept it. I tried variations of `target_compile_definitions()`, but as you've pointed out, I don't want to add a definition. `target_compile_options(<target> PRIVATE -include ; <path-to-header>)` was just what I was looking for. Somehow I managed to miss that in my search. For anybody else stumbling upon this, I believe the semicolon is require to generate a list argument to the command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this the following way to not confuse CMake:

```
target_compile_options(<target>
    PUBLIC
        -include/path/to/file.h
        -include./local-file.h
        -include${VARIABLE_STARTING_WITH_SLASH_OR_DOT}
)
```

Basically no space between `-include` and the value.